# Is it permissible to wear a turban-style hijab with visible earrings?

Tags: hijab

There is a style of hijaab worn by wearing the headscarf as a "turban".  Typically but not always the lower part of the ears are displayed with earrings (earrings aren't tucked under the scarf). The neck is not covered by the headscarf so a Turtle Neck top is worn to cover it. Is this style permitted by any scholars in the Sunni world? Doesn't seem to make sense to wear visible earrings in front of non mahrams as they are a form of attraction for them no?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 1):

It's impermissible in two ways:

- A woman's ears are ordinarily considered part of her awrah and thus it is impermissible to expose them to non-mahram men.  Example fatawa making this claim:

  > While wearing the ‘hijab’ (to cover the head) it is farz (essential) for a woman to cover the ears. It is haram (unlawful and sinful) for women to show their earrings while wearing their hijab. -- Mufti Waseem Khan, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/darululoomtt/52518) (Hanafi, Sunni)
  >
  > The fuqaha’ are agreed that a woman’s ears are ‘awrah and it is not permissible to show them to non-mahrams. -- [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/9611) (Salafi, Sunni)
  >
  > The ears are not considered part of the face as far as the obligation of covering the ʻawrah (body parts that must be covered as per the sharee'ah) is concerned. The woman is obliged to cover the ears as part of the head. -- [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=324592)
  >
  > The ears are not part of the face, therefore it is obligatory to cover them. -- [Ayatollah Sistani](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/46/2066/) (Shia)
- Exposing one's adornments to non-mahram men is further impermissible:

  > And tell the believing women to... not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof... -- [Qur'an 24:31](http://quran.com/24:31)

However, I would not interpret wearing earrings (whether or not she's exposing her ears) as an attempt to attract men.  There's plenty of other reasons that a woman might want to wear earrings, e.g. expressing her femininity.  We should assume the best in other Muslims and avoid suspicion.

There's debate as to what constitutes hijab.  As an example, [Lamya Kaddor](https://en.qantara.de/content/the-german-islam-scholar-lamya-kaddor-why-i-as-a-muslim-woman-dont-wear-a-headscarf) (whose scholarly credentials have been contested in the comments) regarded the "headscarf is obsolete".  At worst, she is merely mistaken.  Likewise, it's possible that the women who wear this turban-style hijab believe it is permissible and are, at worst, mistaken.  (The point of this is: let's go easy on our Muslim sisters who wear the turban-style hijab.)

[NB. In the previous version of this answer, I mentioned [Sheikh Mustapha Mohamed Rashed](https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2012/06/45564/hijab-is-not-an-islamic-duty-scholar/), although this is [reported as fabricated](https://muslimvillage.com/2012/08/12/26678/our-soul-deserves-better-than-a-facebook-islam/).]

Comment: Lamya Kaddor is by no stretch of the imagination an islamic scholar, she is a reformist liberal with muslim background. Some of her views include that disbelief is not related to whether someone will end up in hell, she rejects at least some hudud as obligatory parts of fiqh, she vehemently stands for equality of men and women, she rejects polygyny and slavery as a matter of principle.

Comment: I agree with G.Bach, Lamya Kaddor is certainly not an islamic scholar, and the other one is just a student who is defending his thesis, which does not make him an islamic scholar by any mean. There are no islamic scholars who say that women should not cover their head. Evidence of that in Quran and Sunnah is more than one can count. I don't think it is a good practice or even fair to cite those people as credible sources of Islamic teaching.

Comment: Apparently [Al-Azhar denies](https://muslimvillage.com/2012/08/12/26678/our-soul-deserves-better-than-a-facebook-islam/) that anyone by the name of Mustapha Mohamed Rashed submitted a thesis, or that a thesis suggesting the headscarf is obsolete was presented by anyone, let alone accepted, and they reject the suggestion that they would grant a PhD for such a thesis as "literally impossible". The story seems to be a hoax.

Comment: Fascinating.  I also regard covering one's hair as obligatory (and wear it myself).  I write the last part to establish that there are other interpretations.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones If that's what you're trying to establish, then references to people that actually exist and are authorities in fiqh (as opposed to inexistent people and laypeople) would be necessary.