# Is Lamya Kaddor an Islamic scholar?

Tags: islamic-scholar

In my answer to [Is it permissible to wear a turban-style hijab with visible earrings?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36410/17163), I referenced an article by *German Islam Scholar Lamya Kaddor* who makes the claim...

> Does the Koran really demand that women wear headscarves? Or is it mainly older men who claim they can decide how women should dress – with no theological foundation whatsoever? For the **Islam scholar Lamya Kaddor**, there is no question about it: the headscarf is obsolete -- Lamya Kaddor, [Why I as a Muslim Woman Don't Wear a Headscarf](https://en.qantara.de/content/the-german-islam-scholar-lamya-kaddor-why-i-as-a-muslim-woman-dont-wear-a-headscarf), qantara.de, 2011

She doesn't question that hijab is obligatory, just that the headscarf is part of hijab.  Nevertheless, it's clearly an unorthodox position in Islam.

In response to citing this article, her scholarly credentials were strongly questioned by two users.  However, neither comment supported their claim with evidence.  Hence the question...

**Question**: Is Lamya Kaddor an Islamic scholar?

Her Wikipedia page indicates she has experience in teaching Islam:

> Lamya Kaddor is... a writer and founder and chairwoman of the Liberal-Islamic Association (LIB e.V.). She is known for introducing Islamic education in German in public schools in Germany. Together with Rabeya Müller she has published the first German Qur'an translation for children and adults: "Der Koran für Kinder und Erwachsene". Furthermore she is initiator and editor of the first German school book for Islamic education called "Saphir". Especially since 2014 she works on the subject of Salafism and Islamism. Five of her former students volunteered for jihad in Syria, which Lamya Kaddor perceived as a personal defeat. ... She taught Islamic education in a secondary school in Dinslaken in North Rhine-Westphalia.  -- [Lamya Kaddor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamya_Kaddor), Wikipedia

Some news articles about her refrain from using the word "scholar":

> Lamya Kaddor, a German-Syrian religious studies teacher and expert on Islam... -- [After Students Went To Wage Jihad, Teacher Highlights Youth Radicalization](http://www.npr.org/2015/03/21/394500965/after-students-went-to-wage-jihad-teacher-highlights-youth-radicalization), 2015
>
> ...she speaks German, Arabic and Turkish.  She also trains teachers in the teaching of Islamic religious studies at the University of Münster, the first program of its kind in Germany. -- Beate Lakotta, ['Anyone Who Wants Integration Has to Provide Islam Instruction'](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany/german-schools-introduce-muslim-classes-anyone-who-wants-integration-has-to-provide-islam-instruction-a-541440.html)

Comment: I don't know her background that well, but i can tell you that she is more acknowledged by german authorities than by Muslims in germany.

Comment: From a classical perspective she definetly isn't more a scholar than you and I.

Comment: The wikipedia you quote says nothing about her education, only about what teaching roles she had. The German state has no wish to spread orthodox Islam in its classrooms, and Lamya Kaddor being the best known teacher of Islamic education in Germany reflects that very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call Lamya Kaddor an Islamic scholar.

On her [website](https://lamyakaddor.jimdo.com/%C3%BCber-mich/) she describes her higher education in regards to Islam as being a study of Arabic and Islamic Sciences at the German University of Muenster.

A look at the [university's](https://www.uni-muenster.de/ArabistikIslam/Studieren/index.html) website for a description of this 4 year degree course shows, that it is mainly based on studying Arabic language in a way to be able to read  original texts. Islamic Sciences are being taught in a very basic way and do not cover all areas normally being included in a classical study of Islam.

Her liberal viewpoint and her approach to modernise the religion of Islam go well with the German authorities. Therefore, she plays a leading role in teaching Islam in German schools as well as in teacher training.

Comment: Perhaps worth including that according to her website, her only credential in Islamic doctrine seems to be an honorary PhD in Islamic theology from [this place](http://edu.gen.tr/) - which she feels is worth including, or accepting.